# How can I protect some wiki page in TRAC?

Tags: trac

I have TRAC instance running and I need to protect few specific pages from some authenticated users, while giving access to those pages to certain other users.

*** UPDATE *** : Authenticated users have `wiki_view` privileges, but I need to prevent certain users from accessing certain wiki pages, without blocking them from access any wiki pages.

Is this something that can be done?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough as answers are not going right directions (my fault).

Answer (score 1):

Would you not be able to use one of the apache authorisation configuration options and/or modules to add an authentication layer based on the url?

With the right /location settings you should be able to get this done.

```
<Location /secure>
  AuthType basic
  AuthName "private area"
  AuthBasicProvider dbm
  AuthDBMType SDBM
  AuthDBMUserFile /www/etc/dbmpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

See also:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_digest.html

Answer (score 1):

Trac has it's own built-in authentication. Why not use that?

> Permission privileges are managed using the trac-admin tool or (new in version 0.11) the General / Permissions panel in the Admin tab of the web interface.

[TracPermissions - The Trac Project](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPermissions)